# Update image from url only if it has been modified android

Tags: android, http-headers

With Java, how do I return the headers for just the image? I can get the last time the file on my phone was modified...

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
sdf.format(file.lastModified()));
```

So I am down to getting the last updated from the server... if it's different, download it, else don't worry about it.

What I am afraid of is hitting the server too much. I'd like to keep that load down. Is this a good solution for that?